# Downcasting double to int which rounding mode?

Tags: java, rounding, downcast

Which of the following rounding mode is followed by casting a double to an int?

Result of rounding input to one digit with the given [rounding mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)

```
Input                                                   HALF_EVEN
Number  UP      DOWN    CEILING FLOOR   HALF_UP HALF_DOWN       UNNECESSARY
5.5     6       5       6       5       6       5       6       throw ArithmeticException
2.5     3       2       3       2       3       2       2       throw ArithmeticException
1.6     2       1       2       1       2       2       2       throw ArithmeticException
1.1     2       1       2       1       1       1       1       throw ArithmeticException
1.0     1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
-1.0    -1      -1      -1      -1      -1      -1      -1      -1
-1.1    -2      -1      -1      -2      -1      -1      -1      throw ArithmeticException
-1.6    -2      -1      -1      -2      -2      -2      -2      throw ArithmeticException
-2.5    -3      -2      -2      -3      -3      -2      -2      throw ArithmeticException
-5.5    -6      -5      -5      -6      -6      -5      -6      throw ArithmeticException
```

I know that it's not related to casting primitives the enum I have quoted, however the table surely covers the way that a double gets downacasted to an int. Which one of the list does that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: to anyone interested in reading the table properly, click on the link "rounding mode" above posted

Comment: Interesting that with all those rounding modes, they didn't include floor(x+0.5), which I'd expect to be more often useful than half_up or half_down (in graphics, one should generally pick a rounding mode such that round(x+1) = round(x)+1 for all values of x where round(x)+1 is representable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which of the following rounding mode is followed by casting a double to an int?

It simply truncates towards zero - is represented by the confusingly-named `DOWN` in your question.

From [section 5.1.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type T takes two steps:
>
> In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a `long`, if `T` is long, or to an `int`, if `T` is `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`, as follows:
>
> - If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the first step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
> - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then there are two cases:
>
> [ ... ]

(The rest isn't relevant to the question.)

Comment: @Rollerball "down" is ambiguous. It can mean "towards zero" or "towards negative infinity". They differ in treatment of negative numbers.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan well I mean "down" meant in the table I have linked in my question.